# Drupal 7 how can I print a current date in page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Please Help, I want to print a current date on the top of my web page, I am using drupal 7.please let me know how can I print a current date in my page.tpl.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line wherever you want to in `page.tpl.php`:

```
echo date('d/m/Y');
```

That will put the date out in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, see [PHP's Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a list of all the possible formats.

Answer (score 1):

hai also use time() function for getting the time stamp

and format the date with drupal function format_date();
[format date](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the constant REQUEST_TIME - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/REQUEST_TIME/7